# Matches special character in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect the string content the special character like this: `ADD[ID,x,y];`

In this case is: `[` and `]`

Is it impossible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to capture the `ID,x,y` part, sure it's possible:

```
var str = "ADD[ID,x,y];";
var match = /\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]); // "ID,x,y"
}
```

The expression is really simple, but it *looks* complicated. So:

- The `/.../` is a regular expression literal.
- The `\[` is a literal `[` character (since `[` is special in regular expressions, we have to escape it).
- The `(....)` is a capture group. We're using it to capture the text within the brackets.
- The `[^\]]` is a character class meaning "anything that isn't a `]` character". We have to escape the `]` on the inside because otherwise it terminates the character class.
- The `+` means "one or more of the previous thing".
- And of course, the `\]` is the literal ending `]` character.

Comment: hi @T.J.Crowder
I've tried the code: var re = /\bn\[n\]n\;\b/i; 
As what I know \b is for detect for begin and end of string. But the input: "n[n]n;" is not allowed. Please show me why?

Comment: And when I change /\bn[n]n\;\b/i to /\bn[n]n\;/i. The input is allowed. What happen with my regular string?

Comment: @TunaTan: `\b` doesn't "detect begin and end of string." It matches a *word* boundary. `^` is start-of-string, `$` is end-of-string. But the expression in the answer above matches the example you gave in your question, why are you going off in a different direction? If you're trying to match different input, why not put that input in your question in the first place?